# How to override scala generic type method with 2D array parameter in Java

Tags: java, scala, generic-type-argument

I have scala class defined as below:

```
abstract class scalaBase[T:ClassTag, U:ClassTag]()
{
    def proc(input:Array[Array[Array[T]]]):Array[Array[Array[U]]];
}
```

While I extend this class in Java and override proc method, the compiler gives errors.

```
class myJavaCls extends scalaBase<Float,Float>() {
    @Override
    public Float[][] proc(Float[][] inTrace) {
        Float[] outTrace = new Float[inTrace[0].length];
        return new Float[][] { outTrace };
}

}
```

Error:

```
error: myJavaCls is not abstract and does not override abstract method proc(Object[]) in scalaBase.
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: looks like you need to override a `proc(Object[])` method as well (note single dimension array).

Comment: I just wonder how to override this proc function in subclass. When I disassemble the base class, the proc method is:  `public abstract java.lang.Object[] proc(java.lang.Object[]);` Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you could add another function `public Object[] proc(Object[]) {  }`.

Comment: @McAngus Do you means add `public Object[] proc(Object[]) { }` in the myJavaCls class? How to implement the codes and what do they mean? Thanks!

Comment: You could just add that function and return a `new Object[inTrace.length]`. This is mostly just to appease the compiler. You don't have to use that function elsewhere.

Comment: @McAngus I could add `@Override public Object[] proc(Object[]) { }` for cheating the compiler. But I still need to implement the actual logical codes in 'public Float[][] proc(Float[][] inTrace) {}`. The actual proc function seems not be called at run time.